# How do I get the field referenced by a foreign key, when implementing admin.py

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-forms

Suppose I have two models `Group` and `User` which are implement and related like in the official docs for Many-to-one Relationships of Django with a ForeignKey, (Group=Reporter and User=Article)

On the Django Admin Backend, I want to display the User with the Email Address of the corresponding Group. (Each group has a designated Mail-Address)

The `User` in models.py is:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

The `Group` in models.py is simply:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My admin.py with the Class that displays my User GUI looks like this:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin)
    [...]
    
    list_display = ('id', 'username', 'group_email')

    def group_email(self, obj):
        # return obj.group.email # [1]
        # return obj.group       # [2]
    
    [...]
```

So if you look at the function `group_email()`, [1] returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'`. Why is the Group Object a 'NoneType'? Even though a `type(obj.group)` returns `<class 'myapp.base.models.Group'>`. [2] returns the name of the group (as it is specified in the **str**() function of the `Group` class). So [2] is working. But why does [1] not find the `email` attribute as it is specified in the `Group` Model?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have answered it myself... In my Database there was actually another `User` that was not assigned to a `Group`. Therefore when setting up the overview in Django Admin GUI, Django tried to fetch the field `email` of `NoneType` and threw the Exception. It didn't get to the next records in the Database, where the Users were properly assigned to a Group. Lessons Learned: Check your source and check your data that you feed to you source...

In case anyone wants the code, that fixed my issue:

```
def group_email(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj.group, Group):
        return obj.group.email
```